# I am using react-native here and the library react-native-google-places-autocomplete I have imported my API key but autocomplete is not working. pleas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

this is the code Which I have written please help.
I am using react-native here and the library react-native-google-places-autocomplete I have imported my API key but autocomplete is not working. please help

```js
import { SafeAreaView, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import tw from 'tailwind-react-native-classnames';
import NavOptions from '../components/NavOptions';
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY } from "@env";

const HomeScreen = () => {
   // console.log(GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY) HERE I AM GETTING A OUTPUT
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tw`bg-white h-full`}>
            <View style={tw`p-5`}>
                <Image
                    style={{ width: 100, height: 100, resizeMode: "contain" }}
                    source={{
                        uri: "https://links.papareact.com/gzs"
                    }}
                />

                <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                    style={{

                    }}
                    query={{
                        key: GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY,
                        language: 'en',
                    }}
                    placeholder='Where from?'
                    nearbyPlacesAPI='GooglePlacesSearch'
                    debounce={400}
                />
                <NavOptions/>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```